# How to parse a locally running URL with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am just playing with Mechanize because I am attending a workshop on Rails security next week and have encountered a difficulty.

If I use this code:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
uri = URI 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-39351833'
page = agent.get uri
```

then the page URL is returned correctly as:

```
{url #<URI::HTTP http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-39351833>}
```

and I can then parse the page. However, I have to use Mechanize against locally installed Rails apps for workshop exercises, and hit a stumbling block.

When I run this code:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
uri = URI 'http://localhost:3000/secrets/1237'
page = agent.get uri
```

and inspect the page, the URL is now:

```
{url #<URI::HTTP http://localhost:3000/>}
```

It has not kept the '1237' from the end of the path. This is just the root page of the app.

What am I missing?

Comment: I see that `secrets/1237` is now `/`. Is Rails redirecting your request to `/`? What does the log say?

Comment: Yep, my bad, sorry. It's not authenticated obviously so the app is redirecting it - correctly !. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Rails is redirecting you.

Check your log to see what the HTTPd says.